# Need help with dual booting

Tags: boot, dual-boot

I tried dual booting Ubuntu and windows but when I finish the installation it just brings me back to windows. No option for ubuntu or anything. Any replies are greatly appreciated

Comment: What brand/model system? What video card/chip? What version of Windows? UEFI or BIOS installs? May be best to see details, use ppa version with your live installer or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), the auto fix sometimes can create more issues.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: Have tried changing the boot order?

Comment: Yup and it worked

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue once

To solve, it you need a separate boot manager (unless you are comfortable editing the windows registry, which is VERY dangerous). I used rEFInd.
Find out more at http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/index.html

Then you must tell Windows to use it

```
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi
```

Also, shut off fast startup (guide for windows 8, should work for 10) https://www.eightforums.com/threads/fast-startup-turn-on-or-off-in-windows-8.6320/

This assumes your PC uses EFI or UEFI and is 64 bit.

Comment: I tried it and it didn’t work:( still just booting to windows:(

Comment: I edited my post; see it

Comment: Tried what you suggested in your edit, didn’t work. Starting to lose hope and might just wipe windows and install Linux.

Comment: Hmmmm. Are you using UEFI or BIOS? I tried to dual boot with BIOS and ended up using mbr2gpt to convert my windows installation to EFI